# Extracting data from SQL Server with no duplicate of one particular column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Similar questions have been asked before and I tried all those solutions.  Unfortunately none of them worked for me.  Here is my requirement.  There is a table with column1 (which is PK), column2, column3, column4, column5.  Other than the first column (PK), all columns may have duplicate values in different rows.  However, I want to pull a list of all rows with just one condition, column2 must not repeat.  If there are multiple rows with duplicate values in column2, I just want any of the rows (say the first one, which can be done using min(column1))  and disregards the rows that has same values in column2.

I tried group by, didn't work because group by requires me to put all columns in group by and that results in a combination of all columns being unique.

### EDIT

Thank you everybody for putting me on the right track.  I tried many things and finally I think I found the right answer.  Please comment if you see any issues with it.

```
select * from myTable where column1 in (select MIN(column1) from myTable group by  column2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the complete row with the minimum `column1` per value of `column2`, you can use analytic functions to assign an order of the rows ordered by `column1` partitioning by `column2`.

Then you can just pick the rows with row number 1 (the first row per partition) and you'll get the complete existing row with the smallest value of column1;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column2 ORDER BY column1) rn
  FROM test
)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5
FROM cte
WHERE rn=1;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/659d7/3).

Answer (score 0):

Just apply [`MIN()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916.aspx) to all the other columns you want to retrieve, and use `group by` on the one column you want to be unique.

```
SELECT MIN(column1), column2, MIN(column3), MIN(column4), MIN(column5)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY column2
```

**Update**

As mentioned in the comments, the above solution does not return a complete row, but the minimum values across all columns in the group. To retrieve a complete row, based on the lowest value in `column1`:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5
FROM your_table t1
WHERE t1.id = (
  SELECT TOP 1 t2.id
  FROM your_table t2
  WHERE t2.column2 = t1.column2
  ORDER BY t2.column1
)
```

Comment: I will try that. But doesn't MIN require the column to be numeric type?  the columns in my table are all varchar, except the primary key (column1).

Comment: Documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916.aspx). Can be numeric, char, varchar, uniqueidentifier, or datetime columns.

Comment: The problem is that MIN takes the MIN of all rows, which means that you may get column1 from row 1, column3 from row 11 etc, not a complete existing row.

Comment: Actually, it worked like the way I wanted. Now I wait for 8 more minute before I can accept the answer because you decided to answer so quickly after I post the question :-)  Thanks.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson that will be a big issue. But I tested the 5-6 rows in the output.  They seems to match with the rows in the original table.  I will do more checking.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree that @JoachimIsaksson's solution fits your use case better. Feel free to change your accept vote.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thanks for pointing out the error in my ways. It took me a while to come up with a correct solution that didn't mimic yours, though :-)